# Blackberry, having problems code signing first project

Tags: blackberry

I just got done with my first black berry app, and having problems code signeing  it.

I code signed it by right clicking on the project name, 
When the signature tool comes up, under status it has about 13 listings that are green that says signed.
There is another listing that in red say not required, but in category they say required.
The details show
Please contact the signer and register with the Signing Authority. Path: D:\blackberry\CameoMatchingGame\deliverables\Standard\6.0.0\CameoMatchingGame.cod

Under Signer name it is Rim Rim runtime api or Rim crpto api
What did I di wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[Follow these instructions](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/20779/Obtain_and_install_signing_keys_1264848_11.jsp)

Wait a few days, you will receive three emails. Within those emails are your keys. Save those to a safe location.

[Read all of this:](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/codekeys.jsp)

Do what both those links say.

Comment: Hi,Yes I did this, this is so frsutrting, thanks for the reply

Comment: Can't upvote this enough!! Finally a link that isn't out of date! (for now at least)

Comment: ... and now the first link is out of date.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've only added some of the signing keys you needed. Add the rest (there should be 3 total) just like you did the first ones (blackberry->sign->install new keys) and you should be good to go.